# How to un-hide a file that has been hidden on Mac OS 8?

Tags: macos, classic-mac-os

I have a copy of an old folder holding a file that has been hidden on Mac OS 8 or 9 (using resedit, if my memory isn't failing). Is there an easy way to un-hide it in OS X?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Xcode installed you can try the [SetFile](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/Xcode-3.2.5/man1/SetFile.1.html) command. The command below should unhide the hidden file.

```
SetFile -a v hiddenFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the location you saved the file to you can do the following.

Open the terminal and enter these commands.

(show all hidden files)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

(restart Finder)

```
killall Finder
```

Make what ever modifications you need to, and when your done enter these.

(re-hide hidden files)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false
```

(restart Finder again)

```
killall Finder
```