How are these files hidden in Finder?
I have two files here that are hidden, but I cannot determine how they are hidden.  They are found in a folder that users are not normally expected to get to.  I can see them if I use the Finder shortcut Shift+Command+..  As shown in the image below, the names do not start with ., and they are not hidden with the hidden flag (chflag nohidden).  How are these files hidden and how do I unhide them?


See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50444/30895

They have the Finder invisibility attribute, which is not the same as the hidden flag. To remove it:
SetFile -a v 1.dat 2.dat

See the SetFile(1) man page for more information.
